# Django and Tastypie: accessing an object related to a newly created resource

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

Let's assume that I have the following models in my application:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

So my Users own their Categories and I don't want them to be able to post Products in Categories owned by others. I would like to implement my own Tastypie Authorization method (`create_detail`) that will check if the User adding a Product owns the Category he wishes to add this Product to.

My problem is that the method `Authorization.create_detail(self, object_list, bundle)` which I am overriding only receives a `bundle` with an empty `bundle.obj` and some raw data in `bundle.data`. How do I access the `Category` object associated to the `Product` my user wants to create?

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=bundle.data['category'])
```

?

Comment: bundle.data['category'] is a URL and not a django model id.